# Newlines are getting replaced with HTML linebreak in the Django admin

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I am trying to include some HTML templates into the django change_form.html default template for one of my models.
My main goal is to create some charts in the Django backend.

The problem I have been experiencing is that somehow newlines keep getting replaced with `<br />`.
This is particularly troublesome because it destroys the JavaScript code that I'm actually interested in including on the page.

At the moment my approach is using `readonly_fields` on my ModelAdmin class coupled with a function in my model that returns a `render_to_string` of my template.

My model

```
class Link(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(
            'auth.User',
            verbose_name=_('Author'),
            related_name="tinylinks",
        )

        link = models.CharField(
            max_length=2500,
            verbose_name=_('Link'),
        )

        clicks = models.PositiveIntegerField(
            default=0,
            verbose_name=_('Amount of views'),
        )

        def click_statistics(self):
            response = render_to_string(
                'admin/links/link/click_statistics.html', {})
```

The ModelAdmin class

```
class LinkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('link', 'user', 'clicks')
    search_fields = ['link', 'user']

    readonly_fields = ('click_statistics',)

    fieldsets = [
            ('Link', {'fields': ['user', 'link', 'clicks',]}),
            ('Statistics', {'fields': ['click_statistics',]}),
    ]
```

And this would be click_statistics.html

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <div id='stat_line' class='stats_line line' style='display:block'>
                <script id="graphstat_line" type="text/javascript">
                    function graphstat_line() {
                        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);

                        var options = {
                            'legend': "none",
                            'pointSize': 3,
                            'theme': "maximized",
                            'curveType': "function",
                            'width': 430,
                            'height': 220,
                            'hAxis': {minTextSpacing: 80, maxTextLines: 1, maxAlternation: 1},
                            'vAxis': {minValue: -0.5, format: '#'},
                            'colors': ['#2a85b3']
                        }

                        new google.visualization.LineChart( document.getElementById('visualization_stat_line') ).draw( data, options );}
                        google.setOnLoadCallback( graphstat_line );
                </script>
                <div id="visualization_stat_line"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The questions I have are the following:

- Why are newlines replaced with `<br />` when the output of render_to_string is included into the admin change_form.html template?
- Is there any way this behaviour can be stopped?

Comment: "Django" does not do this. Your code is doing it somehow. But since you haven't posted any, we can't help you fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your response Daniel, I will update my question with the code.

Comment: I've ran into this problem too. Definitely seems to be Django's fault. When I print the value inside my admin method, it looks fine, but the result returned to the browser contains "<br/>". Very frustrating. My hacky workaround is to replace all newlines myself, and ensure my inline JS code is properly formatted to evaluate as a single line. Also, don't mind Roseman's rudeness. He's a bit arrogant.

Comment: Thank you Cerin, it's good to know that this is something that someone else has experienced. I went a completely different path in the end and stopped trying to add that template inside the admin.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using django-suit? If so then the problem is in the template `suit/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html`:

```
    {# If multi-fields and wrap controls too #}
     {% if not singlefield %}
        <div class="multi-field-controls">
      {% endif %}

    {% if field.is_readonly %}
        <span class="readonly">{{ field|field_contents_foreign_linked|linebreaksbr }}</span>
    {% else %}
        {{ field.field }}
    {% endif %}

    {# For single field errors#}
    {% if singlefield and line.errors %}
        <span class="help-inline">{{ line.errors }}</span>
    {% endif %}
```

Copy that template to an app which is higher on INSTALLED_APPS or into a directory listed in TEMPLATE_DIRS (so `TEMPLATE_DIR/admin/includes/fieldset.html`) and remove `|linebreaksbr` from the line above.

I ran into this problem months ago, stumbled upon the solution completely by accident.